# Ubuntu 17.10 - Second Monitor disconnecting when opening Gnome Apps

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, multiple-monitors, 17.10

I've recently updated to Ubuntu 17.10. Everything works fine, except the fact, that everytime i open apps like "Settings" or "Evolution Mail", my second monitor (connected via HDMI) gets disconnected. The same happens, when i execute `xrandr`.

I am using `nvidia-384/nvidia-387` proprietary driver from `ppa:/graphics-drivers`, but i'm running on Intel Graphics via `nvidia-prime`

Log files showing nothing suscpicious.

Thanks in advance!